# Android - Assigning Bitmap to ImageView changes size

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

My application takes a photo with the camera of the smartphone. After capturing the photo I want to assign the photo to a ImageView. But then the size of the ImageView changes.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE
    && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

  ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
  Bitmap bitmap = null;
  Bitmap scaledBitmap  = null;
  InputStream in = null;
  Image image = this.getActualImage();      

  try {
    in = cr.openInputStream(this.imageUri);
    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    o.inSampleSize = 1;
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, o);

    ImageView view = null;
    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_face1);                  

    int height = view.getHeight();
    int width = view.getWidth();
    Log.i(TAG, "Scale operation dimenions - width: " + width
        + ", height: " + height);

    scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, width, height, true);
    view.setImageBitmap(scaledBitmap);
    System.gc();
    in.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Camera", e.toString());
  }
```

My layout xml looks as follows:

```
    <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/screen_capture_face2"
    style="@style/linearLayoutVertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="2" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_face1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_dummy_face"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_face"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_face2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/desc_dummy_face"
        android:src="@drawable/dummy_face"
         />

</LinearLayout>
```

After I assign the bitmap to ImageView img_face1 the size changes. Why does this happen? What am I missing? I am new to Android and maybe it is just some little mistake.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you are setting `adjustViewBounds` to `true`. The reference for it says:

> Set this to true if you want the ImageView to adjust its bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

You could try removing it, and additionally add the `scaleType="fitCenter"` option so that is the image which is resized instead of the image view. You will also want to change the `wrap_content` values from its layout attributes, as those say *make this view big enough to show its entire content*.